# OleDB not supported in 64bit mode?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, 64-bit, oledb

I've been using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 and Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 to read in .csv, .xls, and .xlsx files.

I just found out that neither of these technologies are supported in native 64bit mode!

I have 2 questions:

1. What is the supported way to
   programatically read .csv, .xls, and
   .xlsx files in 64 bit mode.  I just
   can't find answers to this anywhere.
2. If I can't read in all three file
   types, what is the best way to read
   in .csv files in a 64 bit
   environment?

Notes:

- I'm using .NET (3.5p1)
- This is a shrink wrap app; redistribution is a
  key factor.

**Update:**

I can use CorFlags to force the application to run in 32bit mode, which works, but is not desirable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a discussion of what to do [about deprecated MDAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx).  I am afraid the answer is not very satisfying ...

> These new or converted Jet
>   applications can continue to use Jet
>   with the intention of using Microsoft
>   Office 2003 and earlier files (.mdb
>   and .xls) for non-primary data
>   storage. However, for these
>   applications, you should plan to
>   migrate from Jet to the 2007 Office
>   System Driver. You can download the
>   2007 Office System Driver, which
>   allows you to read from and write to
>   pre-existing files in either Office
>   2003 (.mdb and .xls) or the Office
>   2007 (*.accdb, *.xlsm, *.xlsx and
>   *.xlsb) file formats. IMPORTANT Please read the 2007 Office System End User
>   License Agreement for specific usage
>   limitations.
>
> Note: SQL Server applications can also
>   access the 2007 Office System, and
>   earlier, files from SQL Server
>   heterogeneous data connectivity and
>   Integrations Services capabilities as
>   well, via the 2007 Office System
>   Driver. Additionally, 64-bit SQL
>   Server applications can access to
>   32-bit Jet and 2007 Office System
>   files by using 32-bit SQL Server
>   Integration Services (SSIS) on 64-bit
>   Windows.

Comment: Looks like the 2007 Office System Driver is the way to go. The 25mb download is a bit steep, though.

Comment: It's unclear to me that the 2007 Office System Driver's are actually x64, as opposed to just replacement for JET...Has anyone verified that?

Comment: No it is definitely x86 as I just ran into this limitation trying to add SharePoint as a linked server in MSSQL x64. Not applicable to the OP but the way I worked around it was to install a separate x86 instance that linked to the Oledb source and wrapped it with a bunch of views and the x64 instance linked to the x86 instance.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that the Jet DBMS is a 32bit library that gets loaded into the calling process, so you will never be able to use Jet directly from within your app in 64bit mode. As Tim mentioned you could write your own csv parser, but since this is a shrink-wrap app you want something that will handle a wider range of formats. Luckily, there are a number of ways to talk 32-bit apps, so you can still use Jet with a trick.

I would write a little exe that was marked to run only in 32-bit mode. This exe would take a command line argument of the name of the file to read and the name of a temp file to write to. I would use Jet to load the csv/xls, then put the data into an array of arrays, and use the xml serializer to write the data to the temp file.

Then when I need to load/convert a csv/xls file, I would do the following:

```
object[][] ConvertFile(string csvOrXlsFile)
{
    var output = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
    try
    {
        var startinfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("convert.exe",
            string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", csvOrXlsFile, output));

        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo = startinfo;

        proc.Start();
        proc.WaitForExit();

        var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(object[][]));
        using (var reader = System.IO.File.OpenText(output))
            return (object[][])serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(output))
            System.IO.File.Delete(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this option, it keeps things as clean as possible. Its rare that you'll *need* to be running x64 for converting a flat file to your internal data object; however, it is likely you'd want to take advantage of x64 once you have the data in your internal data objects.

Answer (score 4):

You could try the [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) library for your flat-file parsing.  Works amazingly well.

Comment: Thanks Christopher... I did consider FileHelpers, but LGPL is still undesirable to include in a commercial code base as far as I can tell...

Comment: According to the FileHelpers source code for handling Excel files, it makes use of AdoDB which is restricted to 32bit apps. See ExtractDataTable function for additional info.

Comment: @AlexanderN I don't see the source code but I tried with a 64 bits application to read an Excel file and it works perfectly. The same problem with my own old code using Ado throw an exception.

Comment: +1 for this nice library. I love the way I can automap the column of the excel file with properties of my class; it save me a lot of time!

Answer (score 4):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can read and write .csv / .xls / .xlsx workbooks (and [more](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/products/spreadsheetgear.net.aspx)) and supports 64 bit .NET 2.0+. SpreadsheetGear can be distributed royalty free with your shrink wrap applications.

You did not specify whether your application is WinForms or ASP.NET but SpreadsheetGear works with either. You can see live ASP.NET (C# & VB) samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/), learn about the WinForms samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/windowsforms.aspx) and download a free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it yourself.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Comment: Sounds interesting Joe. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use  [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255) to read and write csv, xls access  etc. There is a 32 and 64 bit version of each driver.

Comment: nice!  I hoped something would come up sooner or later from MS

Answer (score 3):

This is more an informational post for anyone that might be experiencing this issue (and for myself incase I have the same problem in the future and can't remember the solution :-))
It's kind of obscure but caused me a few hours of stress, so maybe it'll help someone else...  Sorry if this is repeated (couldn't find it) or deprecated (some don't have the luxury of latest and greatest).

If you are using trying to use Jet 4.0 to access MS Excel documents (or other data files) on a x64-based server, you will have discovered that there is no support for this combination.

The only solution is to allow IIS to run 32-bit applications on Windows 64 and to install a supported db provider.

You'll need to install the driver, 64-Bit OLEDB Provider for ODBC (MSDASQL) that acts as a bridge:
"The Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC (MSDASQL) is a technology that allows applications that are built on OLEDB and ADO (which uses OLEDB internally) to access data sources through an ODBC driver. MSDASQL is an OLEDB provider that connects to ODBC, instead of a database. MSDASQL ships with the Windows operating system, and Windows Server 2008 & Windows Vista SP1 are the first Windows releases to include a 64-bit version of the technology."
Download here : http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=000364db-5e8b-44a8-b9be-ca44d18b059b&displaylang=en

This all works fine, but I came across two things that had me scratching my head (and stressing):
1) You need to allow 32-bit ASP.Net in IIS Web Service Extensions - Read **""http://www.textcontrol.com/blog/permalink/2006082101""** for instructions on both enabling 32-bit apps AND the IIS web service extension setup.
2) If you are using any registry keys under IIS x64, a new node will be added in the registry - Wow6432Node - into which you'll need to move/copy any relevant keys that were used under x64.
i.e. We had a data key stored in HCLM\Software\CustomKey that was no longer available when 32-bit was enabled.  We re-created the key under the Wow6432Node and all was good.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I think Linq is your best solution for this.

Something like....

```
IEnumerable<MyObj> ObjList = GetObjList(yourCSVFileNAme);

var qry = from o in ObjList
          where o.MyField == Something
          select o;
```

and your GetObjList method looks something like

```
Public IEnumerable<MyObj> GetObjList(string filename)
{
  // Obvioulsly you would have some actual validation and error handling
  foreach(string line in File.ReadAllLines(filename))
  {
    string[] fields = line.Split(new char[]{','});
    MyObj obj = new MyObj();
    obj.Field = fields[0];
    obj.AnotherField = int32.Parse(fields[1]);
    yield return obj;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim!  I was hoping to avoid 'rolling my own' csv parsing solution.  I know it's not rocket science, but it is suprisingly subtle sometimes.

Comment: Parsing a CSV file is not as easy as posted (text in parentheses, different separator char for different locales, ...) but there are lots of CSV parsers out there.