# How to Import Excel to Datagrid without OleDB?

Tags: excel, datagridview

my application is 64bit native, therefore the examples on how to import an excel file to a gridview, are useless, due to the OleDB drivers been 32bit only... is there a way around, on how to import an excel file to a datagrid without using the OleDB connection?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861022/oledb-not-supported-in-64bit-mode/861067#861067) on work arounds for 64-bit OleDB.  As I said in that thread, the answer is not very satisfying at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) will do it and supports 64 bit .NET 2.0+.

You can see live ASP.NET (C# & VB) samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/), DataGrid samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/datagrid.aspx) and download a free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it yourself.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC