# OleDBDataAdapter alternatives

Tags: c#

I am looking at some code which basically gets data from an excel spreadsheet using OleDB (OleDBDataAdapter). Is it possible to use something else in place of OleDBDataAdapter> As using this crashes due to the machine being x64.

Thanks

Comment: all you need is read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4665579/559144

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading from Excel: Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 error on 64 bit systems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672523/reading-from-excel-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-error-on-64-bit-systems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Excel Interop](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel). If you are using Excel 2007 or higher you could use an [OpenXML](http://officeopenxml.sourceforge.net/) library as well. Finally if you want to stick with OleDB you could target x86 in your project's properties to force the Jet driver loaded as x86.